# Python if else time sleep freeze another else function

Tags: python, if-statement

I have python script to check if time matches, then run specific function.

```
while True:
    jam = 60*(60-datetime.datetime.now().minute)
    if jam == 3600:
        url = 'http://192.168.1.5/postdata.php'
        myobj = {'somekey': 'test'}

        x = requests.post(url, data = myobj)
        print("Data Hourly Inserted")
        time.sleep(3600)
    else:
        print("Show every 5 seconds")
        time.sleep(5)
```

As you can see above code, there are 2 conditions:

1. `print("Show every 5 seconds")` will run every 5 seconds
2. `print("Data Hourly Inserted")` will run every hour

`if jam == 3600`, the function will run correctly but the text "Show every 5 seconds" will not show again.

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: After it prints `Data Hourly Inserted` it goes to sleep for an hour before repeating the loop.

Comment: So any idea how to keep it always run?

Comment: What do you mean always run?

Comment: Use a background thread to post the data every hour.

Comment: I need `else` function keep running every 5 seconds

Comment: What about simply removing `time.sleep(3600)`? Or placing `time.sleep(5)` after the if-else block? By the way, isn’t your `else` block useful just for debugging?

Comment: I think you should explain what you need to do instead of asking us to improve/debug your solution. Are you trying to execute an operation every hour and *in parallel* execute another operation every 5 seconds?

Comment: The problem is that when the first condition is met, your program goes to sleep for 3600s or 1hr remove that line.

Comment: @Melebius: If you sleep for 5 seconds, then the next loop the `if jam` will be true again due to the way it is calculated. Better sleep for 60 seconds.

Comment: Isn't the `jam` test the same as `if datetime.datetime.now().minute == 0:`?

Comment: That's why I need the `if else` function keep run on loop even the condition already met.

Comment: @quamrana Sleeping for 60 seconds would block the `else` block, just for a minute instead of an hour. I’d prefer to completely rethink and rewrite the presented code…

Answer (score 3):

Save the hour that the data was posted in a variable. Whenever the current hour changes, post it again.

```
last_hour = None
while True:
    if datetime.datetime.now().hour != last_hour
        url = 'http://192.168.1.5/postdata.php'
        myobj = {'somekey': 'test'}

        x = requests.post(url, data = myobj)
        print("Data Hourly Inserted")
        last_hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour
    print("Show every 5 seconds")
    time.sleep(5)
```